# Star a song in spotify from an external source?

Tags: api, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm looking for a way to star a song in Spotify without having to go to the app itself.

For instance: 
I'm playing a game on fullscreen, or I'm working on something and Spotify is on for music. I hear a great song and I want to star it.

Now instead of going to the app, I want to star the song using a shortcut or a dedicated external button.

Whether it is a shortcut, a USB button, or a button on a remote, I believe this function would be really helpful. I've searched through the Spotify core API, but I couldn't find anything that enables me to "star" a song.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged CocoaLibSpotify in this question, well, CocoaLibSpotify has this functionality built right in - the `SPTrack` object has the `starred` property. It'd be fairly simple to write a little app that, when triggered, fetches the currently playing track using the Spotify client's AppleScript bridge and use CocoaLibSpotify to star it.

Alternatively, the Apps API can star a track as well (the `Track` object has the `starred` property). You could use the `player` object to get the current track and star it. However, linking that to an external button will be tricky. One (hacky) way would be to have the button trigger a system URL launch of `spotify:app:star-this-track:invocation:1` where the number at the end increments each time you push the button. Then, the application's `ARGUMENTSCHANGED` event will fire, at which point you can star the track.